# How to solve conflict between `biblatex`, `url` and `enumitem`?

Tags: biblatex, ieeetran, enumitem, urls, journal

First of all I would like to know why does this packages collide when working together. If I don't use `biblatex` there won't be any problem, but if I use it then the packages won't work any more.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
I have cited this document \cite{Smith:2012qr}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the `reference.bib` file if needed:

```
@BOOK{Smith:2012qr,
    title = {{O}nly a {T}est.}
}
```

### Preventing error:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
%\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
I have cited this document %\cite{Smith:2012qr}
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

## Questions:

- What causes the problem?
- How can this problem be solved?

Comment: The only error I get is the option clash with `url` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That is right, why does this happen when using package `biblatex`? How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) already loads the [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package, but without the `hyphens` option. So if you try to load it (again) with this option afterwards, LaTeX gives the appropriate error message. Changing the order in which you load the two packages solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
I have cited this document \cite{Smith:2012qr}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```